# Cloudbees: how to override jvm version for Cloudbees Tomcat applications:

Tags: tomcat, jvm, cloudbees

I am using Cloudbees Jenkind build and deploy of a Tomcat based web application.
It looks like there is a jvm mismatch between Jenkinds build 
where I choosen JDK 1.7 and the default jvm version that is used by Cloudbees Tomcat.

how to set the jvm version for cloudbees Tomcat jvm ?

Answer (score 2):

run SDK command :

```
bees config:set -a <account>/<appId> -Rjava_version=1.7
```

this set "runtime parameter" java_version to 1.7 (java 7).

Answer (score 0):

I found that no matter what settings you put for Jenkins (including building to 1.7), it won't run the app with 1.7 until you use the SDK command mentioned above. At this point in time there appears to be no web based config option to do this. The good news is once you have issued the command, the setting sticks and all future deploys will use Java 7.